# PHP Namespaces, the use command

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm just learning about PHP Namespaces and I have a very simple code which is not working and I'm wondering why:

we have `n1.php` containing one namespace and a function:

```
<?php
namespace app\cat1;
function echoo(){
    echo "from cat 1";
}
?>
```

`n2.php`:

```
<?php
    namespace app\cat2;
    function echoo(){
        echo "from cat 2";
    }
?>
```

now in `index.php` I have included both n1.php and n2.php to use the `echoo` function:

```
<?php

require_once('n1.php');
require_once('n2.php');

use app\cat1;
echoo();

?>
```

As far as I understood the namespacing, the above code should work but it isn't and I don't know why!? I told PHP to use `app\cat1;` and the called `echoo()` function but I get:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function echoo() in E:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php on line 7
```

Ofcourse I can do this and it's gonna work:

```
<?php

require_once('n1.php');
require_once('n2.php');

//use app\cat1; <-- this is commented
app\cat1\echoo(); // <-- and now I'm using full path to run the echoo()
?>
```

the above is working, but now what's the reason we have `use` in namespacing?

---

Another thing: how can we put namespaces in multiple files like I did above and also not use `include` method? I see in Laravel framework files that this is happening. files only have `use etc\blah` and there is no inclusion and it's working just fine. so how is that happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by default `use` keyword will import the object under the namespace , you need to define that you are using `function`

another thing that you need to pass the function name to `use` so to solve your issue :

```
use function app\cat1\echoo;
```

the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php):

```
// importing a function (PHP 5.6+)
use function My\Full\functionName;
```

so , in your example -*here I'm using grouping name spaces instead of including files as long as most of online IDEs does not support including*- :

```
namespace app\cat1 {
    function echoo(){
        echo "from cat 1";
    }
}

namespace app\cat2 {
    function echoo(){
        echo "from cat 2";
    }
}

namespace {
    use function app\cat2\echoo;
    //  ^^^^^^^^ see this
    echoo();
    // Output : from cat 2
}
```

live example : https://3v4l.org/TATgp

Comment: how can we separate namespace files and put the in multiple files and also not use include method? is there a way for that? i see this happening in Laravel framework files, it only uses `use` and there is no `include`

Comment: I updated my question with the new one in the bottom.